# Scheme operation performed recursively instead of only once

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I'm trying to find the distance between two points in 3D space:

Here is my code:

```
(define (helper p1 p2)
    (if (null? p1)
        0
        (+ (distTo3D (cdr p1) (cdr p2))
           (expt (- (car p1) (car p2)) 2))))

(define (distTo3D p1 p2)
    (sqrt (helper p1 p2)))
```

I thought that defining a helper might make it so that `sqrt` is only called on the element that is returned at the end of the helper function. However given a call such as this:

```
(distTo3D '(1 1 1) '(2 2 2))
```

It returned the wrong answer. After experimenting for a while I saw that it was returning `sqrt(sqrt(1) + sqrt(2))` as if the sqrt was a part of the recursive statement itself.

How can I alter my code such that it only calls sqrt on the last element returned by helper?

Comment: It's usual to call the `helper` from `helper`.  Or else you get `(sqrt (+ (sqrt (+ (sqrt (+ (sqrt 0) (expt ...)) (expt ...)) (expt ...)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `helper` should be calling itself, not the original function:

```
(define (helper p1 p2)
    (if (null? p1)
        0
        (+ (helper (cdr p1) (cdr p2))
           (expt (- (car p1) (car p2)) 2))))
```

Every time you go back through the original function (where `sqrt` is), you're getting another inappropriate `sqrt` tacked on. If you look at the definition of the distance, it's:

```
sqrt( sum( (x_i - y_i)^2 from 0 to n ) )
```

`distTo3D` is doing the `sqrt` part, and the whole sum loop is being handled by your recursive `helper`.

Comment: That's what I get for copying and pasting

Answer (score 1):

You dont need recursion for this.

```
(define (helper p1 p2)
    (expt (- p1 p2) 2))

(define (distTo3D p1 p2)
    (inexact (sqrt (apply + (map helper p1 p2)))))

(distTo3D '(1 1 1) '(2 2 2))
```

Runnable sample: http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=145

Comment: Thank you! This is the very first program I've written in scheme so I didn't really know I had access to all these things.